# An archiving strategy that will allow me to view file contents without uncompressing to disk

Tags: linux, unix, compression

I am running in Unix. I have a folder, which has a set of folders and text files under it. I wish to archive this into a single compressed file.

However, through standard Unix commands, I'd like to read the directory tree of the archive, and also read a specific text file from this directory on the fly, printing to stdout I expect.

Is this possible?

Comment: your are looking for tar , tar xf /some/path/test.tar a/dir/foo will extract 1) create dir a/dir in current dir, 2) bring file foo to a/dir/foo.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you can use [squashfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS), which was designed for what you described.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tar`, for example:

- To list the tree:

  ```
  tar tf foo.tar.gz
  ```

  (I have a [script](https://github.com/grawity/code/tree/master/misc) for formatting the output.)
- To extract a specific file to stdout:

  ```
  tar xfO file.tar.gz path/to/txt
  ```

---

On Linux you can use **[archivefs](https://github.com/tmbdev/archivefs)**, a FUSE-based filesystem which lets you access files directly.

(Though I'm not sure if this is the *same* archivefs that I remember from Ubuntu several years ago, but it also worked in a similar way.)